# How can I display more than 100 relationships

Tags: relationships

We have a company that have 200 relationships. When we try to look up the people civi allows you to select 50 or 100. in our case we have 200 and so when we select 100 from the drop down we are unable to page to the remaining records.
We know they records are in civi but the civi interface is unable to retrieve it.

Thanks In advance

Edward

Comment: Are you trying to display the relationships on the company's relationship tab or in search results?

Comment: Hi Allen,I trying to display the relationships on the companies relationship tab.

Comment: We have a company that have 200 relationships. When we try to look up the people civi allows you to select 50 or 100. in our case we have 200 and so when we select 100 from the drop down we are unable to page to the remaining records. We know they records are in civi but the civi interface is unable to retrieve it. The number of records I displayed on the Relationship tabs. The first 100 records are displayed. But civicrm does not display past 100 records.
Thanks

Edward